# window.parent.frames don't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

```
alert(window.parent.frames.toolbar.location)
```

the alert is undefined in Firefox, IE it work fine.

Comment: window.parent.frames.toolbar object doesn't have a location property. (in firefox) whats the question?

Comment: i have a template that have 2 frames the first frame id "toolbar" have a template that contain a javascript function in the second frame i have template that im trying to call the first template to use the function in it. i made it like that:

    window.parent.frames.toolbar.enableButtons(ISFIRST,ISLAST);

it work on IE but Firefox don't work the error is:

TypeError: window.parent.frames.toolbar.enableButtons is not a function

Comment: how can i make it work in both browsers?

Comment: `Frames` is a list, you need to do `frames[0]` or `frames[1]`.

Comment: Btw this: *(the alert is undefined in Firefox, IE it work fine)*. shouldn't alert undefined, it should throw an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome and FF there's a difference if `toolbar` is either an `id` or a `name` of an `(i)frame`. `.frames.id` will refer to an actual (i)frame element (which doesn't have `location` property), `.frames.name` refers to the `window` within an (i)frame element. In IE both refer to the `window` within (i)frame.

A quick-fix would be to add also/use only `name="toolbar"` attribute to your (i)frame element.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
alert(window.parent.frames[0].toolbar.location);
```

That should work.

As my comment said. `window.frames` is a list containing all frames in a `window`. You need to select the correct window, which I guess is the one with index `0`.

Comment: That's exactly what `.toolbar` is doing in OP's code, it "selects" a correct window, or an (i)frame element depending on the used browser and attributes within the (i)frame tag.