# set blank iframe in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

When I try to set an iframe to a blank, black screen, I get an "access denied" error in IE11 and my app freezes.  I don't get this error in firefox, chrome, or opera.  My code is:

```
iframe1.src = "about:blank";
```

I have also tried:

```
src="javascript: ;"
```

and

```
src="javascript:void(0)"
```

I also tried creating a blank html page to use as a src, but that didn't work either.

Edit: I figured out what the problem was.  In my code, I replaced:

```
iframe1.src = "about:blank";
```

with:

```
document.getElementById("iframe1").src = "about:blank";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is an empty iframe src valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946607/is-an-empty-iframe-src-valid)

Comment: @metadings It's not a duplicate because all of those answers suggest the use of "about:blank"  As I stated in my question, "about:blank" doesn't work.

Comment: How exactly you put the value to `iframe1`? Using `frames` collection? If so, please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28155232/1169519).

Comment: Well it's weird that you get an access denied error... Please post some code, how you create that `iframe`!